# Bigquery convert ''Jan 30 2016 12:00AM" to date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm attempting to convert a string to a timestamp within Bigquery. The question is really simple, how do I convert this string `Jan 30 2016 12:00AM` or `Aug  9 2015 12:00AM` to date?

I have tried referring to the Bigquery documentation but it didn't seem to work:
(https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date)
`select PARSE_DATE('%b %e %E4Y', 'Jan 30 2016 12:00AM')`
`select PARSE_DATE('%b %e %E4Y', 'Aug  9 2015 12:00AM')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input string is actually a *timestamp*, not a date, because it has a time component at the end.  So, consider using `PARSE_TIMESTAMP` instead:

```
SELECT PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %e %E4Y %I:%M%p', 'Jan 30 2016 12:00AM') AS ts_out
FROM yourTable;
```

This would return a timestamp based on the input string.  If you really want a date, you could cast the above to date, or you could just use `LEFT` on the string input to restrict to only the date portion:

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%b %e %E4Y', LEFT('Jan 30 2016 12:00AM', 11)) AS ts_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
SELECT DATE(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %e %Y %R%p', ts))
```

You can test it with dummy data as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Jan 30 2016 12:00AM' ts UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Aug  9 2015 12:00AM' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Aug 9 2015 12:00AM'
)
SELECT ts, DATE(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %e %Y %R%p', ts)) date_from_ts
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

with result

```
Row ts                  date_from_ts     
1   Jan 30 2016 12:00AM 2016-01-30   
2   Aug 9 2015 12:00AM  2015-08-09   
3   Aug 9 2015 12:00AM  2015-08-09
```